# http.get() method is not working in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

My purpose is to consume a REST web service in Angular and I am making some trials right now. Below code is not working and going to error block. How can I identify the problem?

```
 interface UserResponse {
     login: string;
     bio: string;
     company: string;
   }

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        this.http.get<UserResponse>('https://api.github.com/users/seeschweiler')
        .pipe( tap(heroes =>{
             alert()
             }),
          catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
        );
      }
    
      private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
           alert()
      return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
        // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
        console.error(error); // log to console instead
     
        // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
        console.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);
     
        // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
        return of(result as T);
      };
    }
```

Comment: you need to subscribe to observable to launch it

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to observable to launch it:

```
....
constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get<UserResponse>('https://api.github.com/users/seeschweiler')
    .catch(this.handleError('getHeroes', [])))
    .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
  }
  ....
```

Or you can still use pipe if you want to, but you still need to subscribe

```
    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get<UserResponse>('https://api.github.com/users/seeschweiler')
    .pipe(
        tap(response => { 
            console.log(response); 
            /* process your data */ 
            return response;}),
        catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', [])),
        )
    .subscribe(processingResult => /* handle processed response */);
  }
```

Comment: Then why that pipe ?

Comment: @AbhiRam `pipe` is to include some processing operation in chain between value emition and actual reception by the subscriber.

Comment: Yes, you can subscribe directly, updated my answer to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient#get()` provides so called "cold observable". That means, it will not execute anything that is under the hood until there will be a subscriber to that observable. Moreover, multiple subscriptions (by default) will result in multiple request being made (unless you pipe it in specific "shared" way)

So:

```
    this.http.get<UserResponse>('https://api.github.com/users/seeschweiler')
    .pipe( tap(heroes =>{
         alert()
         }),
      catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
    ).subscribe(result=>console.log(result));
```

will make your request.

Please read carefully with understanding the tutorial you are going through (Tour of Heroes) as such aspects are explained there in reasonable details.

Answer (score 0):

As it is returning observable you need to subscribe that value. Here is the solution and results.

`this.http.get<any>('https://api.github.com/users/seeschweiler').subscribe( x => console.log(x));`

Result in console [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwgCc.png):